# Linux: Redirect local traffic through external proxy

Tags: linux, networking, proxy

I want to route all my HTTP and HTTPS traffic through an external proxy for all applications - without relying on the application's capability to use the proxy. The only thing I have found and comes close to what I want is described in this [documentation for TOR](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy) (paragraph: Local Redirection Through Tor). I want to do that but with a normal HTTP(S) proxy. Further research suggests, that it is possible to do this for HTTP but not HTTPS because that would result in certificate errors. However, HTTPS connections can be made through TOR without problems.

So why can this not be done with a "normal" Proxy?

I am aware of solutions like `tsocks` which relies on preloading a library. I would prefer a solution that does not rely on such "tricks" and which does not rely on the application to be started in a certain environment, e.g., opening a terminal and exporting `https_proxy` variable.

PS: The Proxy server is a 3rd party server. I have no administration rights for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can activate a system proxy with these configurations.
if your proxy has no US credentials this:

```
export http_proxy="http://PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
export https_proxy="https://PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
export ftp_proxy="http://PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
```

or for a proxy with credentials

```
export http_proxy="http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
export https_proxy="https://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
export ftp_proxy="http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
```

Comment: or for a proxy with credentials

export http_proxy="http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
export https_proxy="https://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
export ftp_proxy="http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_SERVER:PORT"

Comment: I explicitly stated that I do not want a solution which relies on the client respecting some environment variables. Please read my question before posting an answer.

Comment: then you could use a transparent proxy configuring squid